# Transfer cert-manager certificate from one cluster to another for e2e tests

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, gcloud, e2e-testing, cert-manager

I want to transfer the letsencrypt certificate of my production Kubernetes cluster to the cluster I'm spinning up for e2e tests in GitLab CI.

My goal is to avoid storing the certificate in the CI and inject it through the environment because then I need to update manually and have it there for always rather than just the time of the CI job. I assume that I can't create a certificate for the domain for the e2e cluster because the production cluster keeps running.

I'm exporting the secret which is used by the ingress with `kubectl get -o yaml` and importing it into the newly created cluster with `kubectl apply`. This works fine for `microk8s` locally.

My production and e2e cluster are in the Google Cloud. The ingresses don't get IP external addresses because they're complaining `Issuer resource "letsencrypt-prod" not found`. I need the IP address to configure name resolution for the test to point to the e2e cluster rather than production.

I tried adding a

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: admin@mereet.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    http01: {}
```

into the namespace where the ingresses are created and into the namespace where `cert-manager` is installed.

What is the missing issuer referring to and how can I make the certificate transfer work which already works from production to local.

Comment: It sound sketchy to want to use the same certificate that you use in prod for test as well. Why not have a separate certificate for test?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta That's a good point. I guess I wanted to do highly automated e2e testing before automating certificate creation. It's hard to do things wrong on purpose :) If you drop that in a sentence I'll reward you the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, glad that got you headed in the right direction . I'll drop it in an answer now.

Comment: Official cert-manager docs for backup/restore (including certificates) can be found at https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/backup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poor security practice to use the same certificate for your production environments and your test environments. You should generate a separate certificate for the test environment and look to automate its generation to enable highly autmamted end-to-end testing.